# How to do the Update query that bring the info over (MYSQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok, I hvae a simple table that have 5 columns.

```
ID - No - Text - Type - DependentID
21 - 1 - Text1 - 8
24 - 2 - Text2 - 2
32 - 3 - Text3 - 3
34 - 4 - Text4 - 6
44 - 5 - Text5 - 7
33 - 6 - Text3 - 1
38 - 7 - Text4 - 8
45 - 8 - Text5 - 7
```

Requirement: The system will read from top to bottom (based on the ASC order No), if it see a row that has Type>3, then it will look for the previous **closest** row that has type=1 or 2 or 3, if it found one, then it will bring the ID of previous closet Type (1/2/3) into DependentID, if it did not find any previous closest type 1/2/3, then it will put zero into the dependentID.

Note: It won't update for the row that have type=1,2,3.

So after updating the result will be like this:

```
ID - No - Text - Type - DependentID
21 - 1 - Text1 - 8 - 0
24 - 2 - Text2 - 2 
32 - 3 - Text3 - 3 
34 - 4 - Text4 - 6 - 32
44 - 5 - Text5 - 7 - 32
33 - 6 - Text3 - 1
38 - 7 - Text4 - 8 - 33
45 - 8 - Text5 - 7 - 33
```

So how to do the Update query to bring the ID over in this case?

Can we use session variable in mysql to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the previous dependent id using a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select id
        from table t2
        where t2.type in (1, 2, 3) and
              t2.no < t.no
        order by t2.no desc
        limit 1
       ) as NewdependentID
from table t
where t.type > 3;
```

(Actually, this gives `NULL` for no match, but that is ok.)

You can put this query into an `update` with a join:

```
update table t join
       (select t.*,
               (select id
                from table t2
                where t2.type in (1, 2, 3) and
                      t2.no < t.no
                order by t2.no desc
                limit 1
               ) as NewDependentID
        from table t
        where t.type > 3
       ) tdep
       on t.no = tdep.no
    set t.DependentID = coalesce(tdep.NewDependentID, 0);
```

Comment: can u modify ur update query, it got err "Duplicate column name 'dependentID'"

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `UPDATE` with a couple of `LEFT JOIN`s. The `m2` left join is to find all previous matching rows, and the `m3` left join is there to eliminate all but the best match;

```
UPDATE mytable m
LEFT JOIN mytable m2 ON m.No > m2.No AND m2.Type <= 3
LEFT JOIN mytable m3 ON m.No > m3.No AND m3.No > m2.No AND m3.Type <= 3
SET m.DependentId = COALESCE(m2.id, 0)
WHERE m3.No IS NULL AND m.Type > 3
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3095f7/1).

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your answer, but i using the old MYSQl version5.0 or sthing, so i got this error: "Table 'm3' is marked as crashed and should be repaired" after ran ur updating query

Comment: can u use query that compatible to the older mysql version?

Comment: Sorry, don't have access to a that old MySQL version, it works well on 5.1 but that's the oldest I can easily test. MySQL does make it a bit cumbersome to rewrite the query in another way since it (afaict) won't allow subqueries on the updated table.

Comment: thank you, i think i can do select query & then capture data & update later, so it take 2 steps but it can prevent the SQl version problem